# Datastore GeoSpatial queries returns nothing

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to work with Google Datastore database as my backend db, and query it with geospatial queries as in [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/geosearch) tutorial by Google, but all the queries return nothing. I made the next demo debugging servlet in Java:

```
private static final String tableName = "DEBUG";
private static final double radius = 100 * 1000; //100 km
private static final String NameKey = "Name";
private static final String LocationKey = "location";

//Parameters from the http servlet request
String name;
float lat, lng;

//Insert a new person to the DB

Entity person = new Entity(tableName);
person.setProperty(NameKey, name);
GeoPt location = new GeoPt(lat, lng);
person.setProperty(LocationKey, location);
datastore.put(person);

//returns the users in the radius

Query.Filter filter = new Query.StContainsFilter(LocationKey, new Query.GeoRegion.Circle(location, radius));
Query query = new Query(tableName).setFilter(filter);

PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(query);

JsonArray users = new JsonArray();
for (Entity entity : pq.asIterable()){
    users.add(new JsonObject()
         .add(NameKey, (String)entity.getProperty(NameKey))
         .add(LocationKey, ((GeoPt)entity.getProperty(LocationKey)).toString()));
}

result.add("Users", users);
```

The insertion to the DB works, Here is a screenshot from the Google console:

[image: screenshot]

But the query always fails, and throws:

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: DebugGeoPtServlet: Returns: {Error=no matching index found.
The suggested index for this query is:
    <datastore-index kind="DEBUG"  source="manual">
        <property name="location" mode="geospatial"/>
    </datastore-index>

}
```

I don't know what is wrong in the code. I copied it as it in the tutorial, and the points I inserted are very close (Not, even close the 100 km radius)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this index definition to your `datastore-indexes.xml` file (in `/WEB_INF` folder). It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datastore-indexes
  autoGenerate="true">

    <datastore-index kind="DEBUG"  source="manual">
        <property name="location" mode="geospatial"/>
    </datastore-index>

</datastore-indexes>
```

Typically, when you try different queries in your development server, it creates the necessary index definitions automatically. Sometimes, however, you may need to add them manually.

Comment: I seems I don't have one, In my project (Android Studio IDE):
Backend
     src
        main
           java
           resources
           webapp
               WEB-INF
                   appengine-web.xml
                   logging.properties
                   web.xml
               index.html

Should I add it manually?
Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, add it. I will update the answer with a sample.